# pepflashplugin-installer doesnt download properly

Tags: 12.04

I'm trying to get flash for chromium on ubuntu 12.04, but when i try to install it from terminal `sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer` I get dialog with error

```
Failure to download extra data files

The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

pepflashplugin-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now.  Running this command requires an active Internet connection.
```

Clicking run this action now doesn't help because it just fails and opens the dialog again.

and it is not possible to proceed with `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install` because "command not found".

Comment: Can you run it with `--verbose`? Therefore  `sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install --verbose` Please paste output f this command here

Comment: "command not found" again. There is problem with downloading the installer itself (or the extra data to be specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to re-install today with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install flashplugin-installer` and suddenly installation was successful.