# Failure to download extra data files [pepflashplugin-installer] download issue

Tags: software-installation, plugins, pepperflash

I've searched through all the messages relating to this issue & have tried all the solutions but still get this persistent box that pops up. It happened after a recent software update about a couple of weeks ago. I've tried solutions found here: 
[pepflashplugin-installer doesnt download properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598387/pepflashplugin-installer-doesnt-download-properly)

Still have problems.
When I re-installed, I got this info in my terminal:

```
Unpacking flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.644ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.2) ...
flashplugin-installer: processing...
flashplugin-installer: downloading http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz [27.2 MB]
Fetched 27.2 MB in 8s (3,385 kB/s)                                             
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
Installing from local file /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/adobe-flashplugin_20161108.1.orig.tar.gz
Flash Plugin installed.
pepflashplugin-installer: processing...
pepflashplugin-installer: downloading https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_52.0.2743.82-1_amd64.deb
Err:1 https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_52.0.2743.82-1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/google-chrome-stable_52.0.2743.82-1_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_52.0.2743.82-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Download Failed
Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.2.202.644ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
```

What is preventing this from running properly & triggering this annoying pop up box? I've redownloaded multiple times. My Internet connection is on a T1 line, too.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am still having this issue & have read every thread & tried every trick I can & cannot remove this recurring issue. I keep getting prompted to redownload the flash/pepperflash & then it says it can't download it. I am at my wits end. Can someone PLEASE help me rid this box?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and this helped me to solve it:

1. Remove old package

   ```
   sudo apt purge flashplugin-installer
   ```
2. Update repository list

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install new package

   ```
   sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
   ```

Comment: In 2. you mean 'sudo apt update' right ?

Comment: yes he does @SorenA

Comment: yes, thx for remark

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Rinzwind...but I've done that to no success. Multiple times. Even tried a manual install of the flash plugin. Still getting the boxes.